# My Heroku app using Rails and Postgres suddenly stops working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ssl, heroku, redmine

The error message when I tried to start my app 'lvmine.herokuapp.com':

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
```

$ heroku logs --tail -a lvmine

We got

```
2022-02-06T05:34:41.193073+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-02-06T05:34:43.080374+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 17601`
2022-02-06T05:34:45.446271+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2022-02-06T05:34:45.446285+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.19 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:17601
2022-02-06T05:34:45.446285+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2022-02-06T05:34:45.446285+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2022-02-06T05:34:45.446286+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2022-02-06T05:34:46.018783+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2022-02-06T05:34:46.019530+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `initialize': SSL error: tlsv1 alert protocol version (PG::ConnectionBad)
2022-02-06T05:34:46.019531+00:00 app[web.1]: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "44.200.80.186", user "sajwovtzpjymwu", database "d14n914sh0nmn", SSL off
```

Seems like SSL problem and Postgres error? I have no clues.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you connecting via the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable, or did you hard-code credentials somewhere?

Comment: Looks like some problem with database not listening on the port. See this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host

Comment: @AleksandarPavić, Heroku Postgres is a hosted database product. OP has no way to modify its `pg_hba.conf` or any other configuration settings.

Comment: @Chris I think I am using DATABASE_URL environment variable. From my dashboard/latest activities, I see 

Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GREEN (@ref:postgresql-flat-59028)
Nov 16, 2021 at 10:54 AM · v16
 heroku-postgresql@addons.heroku.com
heroku-postgresql: Update HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GRAY by heroku-postgresql
Nov 7, 2021 at 9:18 AM · v15

I am not sure why my database name changed from .._GRAY to .._GREEN. That was the time I started to have application error.

Comment: @kuolaishu, if you didn't do that yourself there's a good chance your database needed some maintenance. Please check your app's configuration to see if you are actually using `DATABASE_URL` or maybe `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GREEN` instead.

Comment: Check the answer I found [here](https://help.heroku.com/1HMEPGV5/why-am-i-seeing-ssl-error-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version-pg-error-when-connecting-to-my-heroku-postgres-database). Maybe try updating your TLS version?

Comment: @JCrew0 The resolution Heroku proposed `Connections to these Heroku Postgres databases require using TLS v1.2 or v1.3`  did not get me anywhere. So I upgraded my lvmine app to `hobby dev` and Heroku started to charge me $1.33 a week. But I still got `application error` after being charged.

Comment: @Chris I am using [redmine](https://redmine.org/), a project management package based on Ruby on Rails. `database.yml` does not use `DATABASE_URL` nor `_GREEN`, I assume that Heroku defines those environment variables at deployment so Heroku CLI can refer to them later easily. I guess my app connects to database with some environment variables, and I am sure I did hard-code credentials.